# PhpStorm - change color of search results

Tags: phpstorm

If I press **CTRL+F** to search for a specific text then I get this result:
[image]

The contrast is extremly bad and I can't read it.
I searched the whole menu but can't find out how I can change the color for this.

Where can I change the color for search results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must be using some custom or non-standard color schema .. because standard ones (Default + Darcula at very least) have them set pretty visible.

Using search box in Settings/Preferences with `search` as text narrows possible options to few places.

In any case:

1. `Settings/Preferences`
2. `Editor | Colors & Fonts`
3. `General --> Search Results | Text search result`

[image]

Comment: If someone wants to change color of current matched phrase. `Settings -> Editor -> Color & Fonts -> General -> Editor ` change color of `Selection background` and `Selection foreground`