How to distinguish with color found substring in code?
Making global search in a project of PhpStorm 2024.1 and having some code lines  as result

if there is a way to distinguish with color found and selected substring ?
I want to see found text at once, bit now with current setting I hardly can find this substring ?
ADDITIVE :
I searched and did not find anything by “Text search result” key and by path :

?

You're paying for the product. Ask the developers :)

Check the styles mentioned here (all 3 styles under that Search Results node): https://stackoverflow.com/a/43202734/783119

Please read ADDITIVE block

"ADDITIVE : I searched and did not find anything by “Text search result” key and by path" That's because you are at Editor | General while you need Editor | Color Scheme | General
